# How to randomise a matrix element for each iteration of a loop?

Tags: r, loops, matrix, random

I'm working with the `popbio` package on a population model. It looks something like this:

```
library(popbio)

babies <- 0.3 
kids <- 0.5 
teens <- 0.75
adults <- 0.98

A <- c(0,0,0,0,teens*0.5,adults*0.8,
         babies,0,0,0,0,0,
         0,kids,0,0,0,0,
         0,0,kids,0,0,0,
         0,0,0,teens,0,0,
         0,0,0,0,teens,adults
)
A <- matrix ((A), ncol=6, byrow = TRUE)

N<-c(10,10,10,10,10,10)
N<-matrix (N, ncol=1)

model <- pop.projection(A,N,iterations=10)
model
```

I'd like to know how I can randomise the input so that at each iteration, which represents years this case, I'd get a different input for the matrix elements. So, for instance, my model runs for 10 years, and I'd like to have the baby survival rate change for each year. `babies <- rnorm(1,0.3,0.1)`doesn't do it because that still leaves me with a single value, just randomly selected.

Update: This is distinct from running 10 separate models with different initial, random values. I'd like the update to occur within a single model run, which itself has 10 iteration in the `pop.projection` function.

Hope you can help.

Comment: You know you can change `rnorm(1,0.3,0.1)` to, for example `rnorm(2,0.3,0.1)` which returns 2 random numbers? Or you want to implement a loop? Please clarify.

Comment: Hi, I understand that, but say I created `rnorm(n,0.3,0.1)`, where n is the number of iterations of the loop, how would I input these values?

Comment: `library(popbio)

model <- list()
n <- 10
for(i in 1:n){
babies <- rnorm(1,0.3,0.1) 
kids <- 0.5 
teens <- 0.75
adults <- 0.98

A <- c(0,0,0,0,teens*0.5,adults*0.8,
babies,0,0,0,0,0,
0,kids,0,0,0,0,
0,0,kids,0,0,0,
0,0,0,teens,0,0,
0,0,0,0,teens,adults
)
A <- matrix ((A), ncol=6, byrow = TRUE)

N<-c(10,10,10,10,10,10)
N<-matrix (N, ncol=1)

model[[i]] <- pop.projection(A,N,iterations=10)
}`

I don't know it it is what you look for but this saves 10 different models with varying `babies`

Comment: Thanks, that's not exactly what I'm after but it's close. Instead of running 10 full models as you've done here, I'd like each year of the model to take as input one of the 10 values for survival. I'll try to improve my question for clarity!

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer is very late, but here's one approach using expressions.  First, use an expression to create the matrix.

```
vr <- list( babies=0.3, kids=0.5, teens=0.75, adults=0.98 )
Ax <- expression( matrix(c(
         0,0,0,0,teens*0.5,adults*0.8,
         babies,0,0,0,0,0,
         0,kids,0,0,0,0,
         0,0,kids,0,0,0,
         0,0,0,teens,0,0,
         0,0,0,0,teens,adults), ncol=6, byrow = TRUE ))
A1 <- eval(Ax, vr)
lambda(A1)
[1] 1.011821
```

Next, use an expression to create vital rates with `nrorm` or other functions.

```
vr2 <- expression(  list( babies=rnorm(1,0.3,0.1), kids=0.5, teens=0.75, adults=0.98 ))
A2 <- eval(Ax, eval( vr2))
lambda(A2)
[1] 1.014586
```

Apply the expression to 100 matrices.

```
x <- sapply(1:100, function(x) lambda(eval(Ax, eval(vr2))))
quantile(x, c(.05,.95))
5%      95% 
0.996523 1.025900
```

Finally, make two small changes to `pop.projection` by adding the vr option and a line to evaluate A at each time step.

```
pop.projection2 <- function (Ax, vr, n, iterations = 20) 
{
    x <- length(n)
    t <- iterations
    stage <- matrix(numeric(x * t), nrow = x)
    pop <- numeric(t)
    change <- numeric(t - 1)
    for (i in 1:t) {
        stage[, i] <- n
        pop[i] <- sum(n)
        if (i > 1) {
            change[i - 1] <- pop[i]/pop[i - 1]
        }
        ## evaluate Ax
        A <- eval(Ax, eval(vr))
        n <- A %*% n
    }
    colnames(stage) <- 0:(t - 1)
    w <- stage[, t]
    pop.proj <- list(lambda = pop[t]/pop[t - 1], stable.stage = w/sum(w), 
        stage.vectors = stage, pop.sizes = pop, pop.changes = change)
    pop.proj
}

n <-c(10,10,10,10,10,10)
pop.projection2(Ax, vr2, n, 10)
$lambda
[1] 0.9874586

$stable.stage
[1] 0.33673579 0.11242588 0.08552367 0.02189786 0.02086656 0.42255023

$stage.vectors
      0         1         2         3          4          5          6          7          8         9
[1,] 10 11.590000 16.375700 19.108186 20.2560223 20.5559445 20.5506251 20.5898222 20.7603581 20.713271
[2,] 10  4.147274  3.332772  4.443311  5.6693931  1.9018887  6.8455597  5.3879202 10.5214540  6.915534
[3,] 10  5.000000  2.073637  1.666386  2.2216556  2.8346965  0.9509443  3.4227799  2.6939601  5.260727
[4,] 10  5.000000  2.500000  1.036819  0.8331931  1.1108278  1.4173483  0.4754722  1.7113899  1.346980
[5,] 10  7.500000  3.750000  1.875000  0.7776139  0.6248948  0.8331209  1.0630112  0.3566041  1.283542
[6,] 10 17.300000 22.579000 24.939920 25.8473716 25.9136346 25.8640330 25.9715930 26.2494195 25.991884

$pop.sizes
 [1] 60.00000 50.53727 50.61111 53.06962 55.60525 52.94189 56.46163 56.91060 62.29319 61.51194

$pop.changes
[1] 0.8422879 1.0014610 1.0485765 1.0477793 0.9521023 1.0664832 1.0079517 1.0945797 0.9874586
```